# Deleting data from a huge table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have few tables and all of them have approx: 5 million rows and each table has Active column in it. i want to delete the data from all the tables where Active = 0.using delete takes lot of time and also I cannot truncate the table since it has Foreign key constraints and Identity field.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a JR programmer, but if you are deleting something really big where it's only one field (Active = 0), but that would take a long time. you have 2 options in my eyes.

1) Run that query, and be patient.

2) find another way to devide the query into a few smaller queries. Like, active = 0 and user names starting with A-G, then another with usernames from H-P and so on. (pseudo example, but you get the idea i hope?)

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete rows in chunks

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SQLServer/0400__Transact-SQL/DeletingRowsinChunks.htm

Comment: Can you check the link again it says not found

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to keep in mind is replication.  If the table is large, and you have to delete a lot of records, you may want to put a [waitfor delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) after so many deletes have occurred so you don't flood replication commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @batchsize int 10000;

while(1=1)
begin
   delete top (@batchsize) 
   from your_table 
   where isActive = 0;

   if (@@rowcount = 0)
   begin
      break
   end
end
```

If finding rows where isActive = 0 is "expensive" (i.e. that's a non-indexed select), you may want to select the primary key for those rows into a temp table first and then do a delete from your table based on a join with the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

the idea is to replicate the table, recreate the table, and copy the active data

1. SSMS > right click to the table and select Script table as - Create To - New Window (don't execute yet)
2. rename the existing table to another name.
3. run the script on step 1
4. run a copy script from Renamed Table to newly created table

   insert into newtable select * from RenamedTable where active=1
5. drop RenamedTable

and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

This is a template I've used in the past to delete rows in batches, you can give it a try:

```
-- Pick the boundaries of the data you want to delete based on
-- the Primary Key of your table
DECLARE
    @StartID INT, -- Pick the appropriate datatype of your PK
    @EndID INT, -- Pick the appropriate datatype of your PK
    @BatchSize INT, -- Number of rows to delete in batch
    @Count INT -- Temporary counter of rows deleted

SELECT TOP 1
    @StartID = PrimaryKeyID
FROM
    dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY
    PrimaryKeyID ASC

SELECT TOP 1
    @EndID = PrimaryKeyID
FROM
    dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY
    PrimaryKeyID DESC

SELECT
    @BatchSize = 1000,
    @Count = 1

-- You can skip this table if you like
-- The idea is to reduce the number of rows processed
-- in the batch below
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    [ID] INT
)

WHILE @Count > 0
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Temp

    DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
    FROM
        dbo.Table WITH (ROWLOCK)
    OUTPUT
        DELETED.PrimaryKeyID
    INTO #Temp
    (
        [ID]
    )
    WHERE
        PrimaryKeyID >= @StartID
    AND PrimaryKeyID <= @EndID
    AND Active = 0

    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @Count = 0
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END

    -- Move the @StartID
    SELECT TOP 1
        @StartID = [ID]
    FROM
        #Temp
    ORDER BY
        [ID] DESC

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:01' -- delay for 1 second to allow any other queries running to process
END
```

Comment: This will only work if the range of data to be deleted is contiguous on the primary key. A very specialized scenario!

Comment: The OP hasn't really specified any specific constraints on his schema. This was meant to be a template...